# Change enbseries bokeh to standard depth of field?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I am using [Sharpshooters Extreme Graphics Vision ENB - good performance](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/15105). It uses bokeh depth of field effect. I want to change it to standard depth of field without disturbing any other settings. How do I do that

Comment: This is rather specific, have you tried asking this on the mods comments page?

Comment: Asked just now.